# How to display an image without using the "image(x,y)" function in Java?

Tags: java, image

I'm a high school student doing an Intro to Computer Science class and part of our project is displaying an image that we have modified into a window. However, we are not allowed to use  image(x,y) like we've learned, we have to use a double for-loop to reference each pixel and its coordinates to get a color, then assign the color to a pixel on the background image. What I have so far in my setup:

```
    `void setup(){
     PImage background=loadImage("DeathStar_plans.png");
     PImage me = loadImage("FullSizeRender.jpg");
     PImage shrinked = shrinkImage(me);
     PImage nogreen = noGreen(me);
     size(1918,816);
     for (int x=0; x<background.width; x=x+1) {
       for (int y=0; y<background.height; y=y+1) {
        float r=red(x+y*nogreen.width);
        float g=green(x+y*nogreen.width);
        float b=blue(x+y*nogreen.width);
        background.pixels[x+y*background.width]=color(r,g,b);
      }
     }
    `
```

All I get are some really weird colors all over the screen. What's wrong?

Comment: `y*nogreen.width` vs `y*background.width` ?

Comment: nogreen is the image I'm trying to put on top of the background image.

Comment: My point is: are the two widths the same?  If they aren't you'd be getting the wrong positions.

Comment: Ok, I fixed that. Now the picture renders the right size for the image, but the pixel colors are still all wrong. Can you see the problem?

Comment: I do not see a problem that would result in strange colors.  Nothing in the snippet you have posted indicates the problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm sure I'll figure it out.